# MacOS App Sandboxing - read access to referenced files from parsed xml

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

**Aim**

Gain read access to files outside the app sandbox environment WITHOUT a user selecting the files directly.

The idea is that a user selects an fcpxml document (via NSOpenPanel) which is then parsed and all of the filepath strings are collected. I then create URL objects from the filepaths and read those the files at those URLs later.

**Problem:**

With App Sandboxing enabled I am unable to access(read) file URLs that I create using the URL method init(fileurlwithpath).

The Entitlement "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write" seems to only give me access to the user-selected XML file and not the referenced files in the fcpxml document.

Can anyone recommend a way to be able to do this?

Cheers!

Adam

Comment: I forgot to mention the error I get is Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Comment: "filepaths that are referenced inside this xml file"  Which xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify details about the paths you are collecting. Are they relative to the XML document or are they always referring to files in a certain folder?
If it is guaranteed, that the paths you are collecting always point to a common System folder (e.g. "Movies" or "Music"), you can [add an entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5) that allows you to gain read/write access to those folders.

If the files are scattered all over the file system, you could prompt your users to select a common root folder via `NSOpenPanel` and store an [app-scoped Bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) to persist access to the selected folder across app sessions.

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for writing back! The xml is a an fcpxml file - the file references are absolutes paths that could pretty much come from anywhere in the user's system. Thank you for the tip about the app-scoped Bookmark, i'll look into it and see if it is suitable. There are apps that are available on the App Store that read fcpxml and immediately read the referenced files - Apple Final Cut Studio, Davinci Resolve. There must be a way

Comment: Ah. One of my apps (https://www.peakstep.com/claquette/) also deals with fcpxml files. It only exports them though. 
What I noticed while learning about the format: fcpxml stores security scoped bookmarks as base64 data blob in its XML. So you might be able to resolve those bookmarks and gain security access to the asset files. There's some documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/Resources/Resources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011227-CH16-SW9

Comment: Thomas great find! That looks like it might be just what I need to implement.    Will see how I go with it. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Thomas! Thanks for your recommendations - in the end I was able to use the Bookmark to give read access. Cheers!!