# Is there an alternative to NSFileCoordinator for opening related files in a sandbox?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sandbox, sidecar

This is a follow-up to [Access sidecar files in a Mac sandboxed app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14772480/560648).

Though not covered in the answer there, the Apple docs teach us that to access a "related file" we must use an `NSFileCoordinator` for access ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)).

This is a little heavy for my needs, and poses an architectural problem, since the actual file access is in my back-end code, away from the reaches of the Apple library facilities. I don't want to have to use the `NSFileCoordinator` for obtaining the related file's content, if I can help it. I don't want to require my users to manually identify the sidecar file either (if nothing else, this would be a bad workflow for batch processing). I just want to tell the sandbox "this is okay, this app can open such-and-such a related File.XYZ after the user chose File.ABC".

For normal file accesses this isn't a problem: using an `std::ifstream` to [open a file that's been previously selected from an Open panel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_files_user-selected_read-only?language=objc) seems to work for remainder of the app instance's lifetime.

But opening a "related file" seems to be more limited.

Having added a `NSIsRelatedItemType` to my app's plist (as indicated in the linked answer), what is the minimal thing I can do in the front-end, presumably immediately after opening the "primary"/requested file, such that I can also later use an `std::ifstream` to open a related sidecar file? The documentation seems a little sparse on this subject…

Perhaps my best bet is to perform a one-time prompt for the user to authorise access to the encapsulating directory, and save the resulting entitlement as an app-scoped bookmark ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48785789/560648)) but again that's not quite as transparent as I'd like. It would also be perhaps a little "scary" for users to be confronted with such a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the OS will [potentially] actually copy the file to a different location in order to provide you with access to it, so you must use `NSFileCoordinator`.

But all is not lost! There is a hack: even if your back-end code is designed to be portable, if you set the file-reading `.cpp` to be "Objective-C++ Source" in Xcode, you can use Foundation features (`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`) right there.

So wherever you currently instantiate and read-from an `std::ifstream`, have an `#if defined(PLATFORM_MAC_OS_X)` (or whatever) and, inside that, wrap your file-reading with the `NSFileCoordinator` code.

Up top:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_MAC_OS_X
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SidecarPresenter : NSObject<NSFilePresenter>
@property(readwrite, copy) NSURL* presentedItemURL;
@property(readwrite, copy) NSURL* primaryPresentedItemURL;
@property(readwrite, assign) NSOperationQueue* presentedItemOperationQueue;

-(instancetype)initWithImageUrl:(NSURL*)imageUrl andSidecarExtension:(NSString*)newExt;
@end

@implementation SidecarPresenter

- (instancetype)initWithImageUrl:(NSURL*)imageUrl andSidecarExtension:(NSString*)newExt
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setPrimaryPresentedItemURL:imageURL];
        [self setPresentedItemURL:[[imageUrl URLByDeletingPathExtension] URLByAppendingPathExtension:newExt]];
        [self setPresentedItemOperationQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_primaryPresentedItemURL release];
    [_presentedItemURL release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
#endif
```

And later:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_MAC_OS_X
SidecarPresenter* presenter = [SidecarPresenter alloc];
[presenter initWithImageUrl:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentFilename]
        andSidecarExtension:sidecarExtension]];
[presenter autorelease];

[NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:presenter];
NSFileCoordinator* coordinator = [[[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:presenter] autorelease];

NSError* error = nil;
[coordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:presenter.presentedItemURL
                                options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges
                                  error:&error
                             byAccessor:^(NSURL* newURL)
{
   std::ifstream strm([newURL fileSystemRepresentation]);
   foo(strm);
}];

[NSFileCoordinator removeFilePresenter:presenter];

#else
std::ifstream strm(documentFilename);
foo(strm);
#endif
```

In this way, there's no ping-ponging back and forth between the back- and front-end. And the lambda is invoked synchronously so you don't have to worry about race conditions, either (just a bit of extra latency, potentially). The only cost is a bit of platform-specific leakage but at least it's hidden away inside a preprocessor directive.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added a post with a Swift implementation

https://blog.hobbyistsoftware.com/2023/03/how-to-access-related-files-in-the-mac-sandbox/